# What could be wrong with this url?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I have URL:

```
"/Communication/New/?memberId=-1"
```

And following method in controller

```
public ActionResult New(string subject, int memberId = 0)
    {
       //something
    }
```

In JavaScript I have :

```
href="/Communication/New/?memberId=-1"

location.pathname = href;
```

Firefox and Chrome do not throw error and  action New is triggered. 
In Internet Explorer in console I find: "SCRIPT2: The URL is invalid."

I already tried with "/Communication/New?memberId=-1" but same error happens again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pathname is the portion of the URL that appears between the hostname and the query string.

A `?` indicates the start of the query string.

You can't put a query string inside a pathname.

Assign to `location` instead of `location.pathname`.